# Using next_permutation on a array of chars

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, stl

I'm running into an issue while using next_permutation on a null terminated array of characters. When I log inside of the do while statement it only gives me the first character of the charArray that I'm starting with as opposed to giving me the first character of all the possible permutations.  Here is the code:

```
void generatePermutations(int no_ones, int length){

    char charArray[length+1];

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(no_ones > 0){
            charArray[i] = '1';
            no_ones--;
        }else{
            charArray[i] = '0';
        }
    }
    charArray[length] = '\0';

    do {
        std::cout << charArray[0] << std::endl;
    } while ( std::next_permutation(charArray, (charArray + length)));

}
```

Comment: You're only printing the first character of the array in the loop. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yep I was doing that to test and see if it was working. The problem is that it's not printing out any other permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the canonical `do ... while(std::next_permutation)` loop to visit all permutations, you need to initialize your array so that it's in sorted order. The reason for this is that the `std::next_permutation` algorithm computes the permutation that comes next in lexicographical order after the current one. In your case, you've started off with your array in *reverse* sorted order, so the algorithm will return false on the first go.

You could either change your code to initialize the array, or you could keep it and add a call to `std::reverse` beforehand.

Comment: Awesome! That fixed the problem.